# How to get DropDownList Selected Value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have dropdownlist, which I have filled from database. Now I need to get the selected value in Controller do some manipulation. But not getting the idea.

**Models/UserManageClass.cs**

```
public class UserManageClass
{
    // Set Stored Procedure Results to Array
    public sp_GetAllDeveloperType_Result dv { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<sp_GetAllDeveloperType_Result> dvi { get; set; }
}
```

**Controllers/ResourceController.cs**

```
public static db_RIROEntities db_RIRO = new db_RIROEntities();
public static UserManageClass model = new UserManageClass();

public ActionResult NewUser()
{
  model.dv = db_RIRO.sp_GetAllDeveloperType().FirstOrDefault();
  model.dvi = db_RIRO.sp_GetAllDeveloperType();
}
[HttpPost]
// Insert User
public void AddUser(ResourceViewModel resourceInfo)
{

 }
```

**Views**

```
using (@Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "Resource", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
@model OnlineRIRO.Models.UserManageClass
@* Display DropDownList for Developer Type *@

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.dv.DeveloperTypeID, new SelectList(Model.dvi, "DeveloperTypeID", "Developer_Type"), new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label class="lb-sm">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtLastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-sm">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label class="lb-sm">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-sm" id="" value="">
    </div>
</div> 
}
```

How would I pass the Selected Value from the DropDownList into the `ResourceViewModel`?

**ResourceViewModel**

```
public class ResourceViewModel
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Wrap your dropdown inside a form and do a form submit. BTW, Where are you even using the `ResourceViewModel` ? Also your action method code should throw a compile time error as it has a return type of `ActionResult` and your code is not returning anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view model should be the class which represents the properties needed by your view. So if you want to add a dropdown to your view, add 2 more properties to your viewmodel, one for the list of items needed to build the select options and another for the selected option value.

```
public class ResourceViewModel
{
    public int DeveloperTypeId { set;get;}
    public List<SelectListItem> DeveloperTypes { set;get;}

    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Now in your GET action, create an object of this view model, initialize the `DeveloperTypes` collection property and send the object to the view.

```
public ActionResult NewUser()
{
   var vm = new ResourceViewModel();
   vm.DeveloperTypes = db_RIRO.sp_GetAllDeveloperType()
                              .Select(a=> new SelectListItem { 
                                               Value = a.DeveloperTypeID.ToString(), 
                                               Text= a.Developer_Type })
                              .ToList();
   return View(vm);
}
[HttpPost]
public void AddUser(ResourceViewModel model)
{
   //check model.DeveloperTypeId
   // to do : Return something
}
```

Assuming `db_RIRO.sp_GetAllDeveloperType()` returns a collection of objects with a `DeveloperTypeID` property of `int` type and a `Developer_Type` of `string` type.

Now in your view, you can use `DropDownListFor` helper

```
@model ResourceViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddUser","Resource"))
{
   @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.FirstName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.FirstName)

   @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.LastName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.LastName)

   @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.DeveloperTypeId)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.DeveloperTypeId, Model.DeveloperTypes,"Select");

   <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: Really huge help. Thank you. Does this mean that I should disregard the `UserManageClass.cs`?

Comment: If that class is not being used anywhere, delete it. Remember, view model classes should be specific to the view.

Comment: Probably. At the very least get rid of the statics fields. There's almost no place for a static field/property in asp.net. They're shared for ALL requests during the lifetime of the worker process, but not between worker processes